# Open HTML with CSS in JupyterLab tab with full formatting

Tags: javascript, html, css, python-sphinx, jupyter-lab

I create an HTML document using [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/).  When I click on the index.html file it opens a browser and looks like this.  The look depends on some .CSS and .JS files being executed:

[image: sphinx displayed properly]

If I open the same file from the [JupyterLab](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) file browser, it opens in a tab but looks much worse: .CSS and .JS are not displayed, and images are not displayed.  It looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to get JupyterLab to get JupyterLab to execute the .CSS and .JS and pass through any images linked in the text?  The JupyterLab is running on a remote server, so I don't have the option of having it create a new browser process on my local machine, because the files are remote.

Comment: Have you tried pressing "Trust HTML" button? By default JupyterLab protects you from executing (potentially non-secure) javascript embedded in HTML files.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work.  It asks me to "Enable Javascript" and I'm not sure how to do that, it's not doing the enablement.

Comment: That's on a work machine.  On a home machine, I don't get the "Enable Javascript" message, but pressing "Trust HTML" also doesn't do much of anything on the home machine.

Answer (score 1):

Using JupyterLab within JupyterHub (old school install with conda, no docker and such)

I've been stuck at this HTML Preview issue for a few weeks.
I have the very same use case as you (Sphinx stuff for a team to work on their docs).

So far, no luck.

- It may or may not work (depending on... I'm not sure of...) if I'm using JupyterLab from the browser on the hypervisor hosting JupyterHub itself
- It won't work if I'm using JupyterLab from the browser on my client machine.

I tried to mess around with
`c.NotebookApp.allow_remote_access = True` parameter with no luck

- tried to put it in my profile ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
- tried to add it to general config file /path/to/conf/jupyterhub_config.py

=> Not sure of the right way to set this option on JupyterLab's JupyterHub install, nor if it's even a relevant option...
Well, security wise, it's not, that's a given (^^'), but Preview HTML is an important feature for Sphinx users, hope someone can help with this...

I also looked after nginx config, but you get the issue with or without the reverse proxy anyway...

Comment: This is not an actual answer. It looks like a "I have this problem too" comment.

Comment: At least I was trying to build up on this issue.
What is your post's point ?

Comment: My point is that you haven't provided an answer that solves the problem. On the other hand I can understand why you posted the "answer", since you don't yet have enough reputation to post comments on other people's posts.

Comment: I find the non-answer helpful because it confirms that another person can reproduce the problem under the same circumstances.